# Removing characters after the decimal point for a double

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

How can I remove the all the characters after the decimal point.

Instead of 7.3456, I would just like 7.

This is what I do to get the number so far with decimal places.

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %f : %f",(audioPlayer.currentTime),(audioPlayer.duration) ];
```

Many Thanks,
-Code

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can specify what you want using format string :

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.0f : %.0f", (audioPlayer.currentTime),
                                            (audioPlayer.duration)];
```

Comment: This is useful. Changing the value before the `f` changes the decimal places. eg: 1.2345 -> %.0f = 1 -> %.2f = 1.23

Comment: Using this answer, you need to keep in mind that the values are [rounded](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17986616/decimal-value-rounding-off-to-next-higher-value-in-ios) if you use stringWithFormat.

Answer (score 5):

If you want this for display, use an [`NSNumberFormatter`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfNumberFormatting10_4.html):

```
double sevenpointthreefourfivesix = 7.3456;
NSNumberFormatter * formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:0];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:sevenpointthreefourfivesix]]);
```

> 2011-12-20 20:19:48.813 NoDecimal[55110:903] 7

If you want a *value* without the fractional part, use [`round()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/round.3.html). If you want the closest integer value *not greater* than the original value, use [`floor()`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/floor.3.html).

Answer (score 4):

`floorf()` is the function you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

you are after

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %.00f : %.00f",(audioPlayer.currentTime),(audioPlayer.duration) ];
```

When formatting float you can tell the precision by the number before the f

Answer (score 3):

Cast to int:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %i : %i",(int)(audioPlayer.currentTime),(int)(audioPlayer.duration) ];
```

Casting like this always rounds down (eg: just removes everything after the decimal place). This is what you asked for.

In the case of rounding to the NEAREST whole number you want to add 0.5 to the number

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %i : %i",(int)(audioPlayer.currentTime+0.5f),(int)(audioPlayer.duration+0.5f) ];
```

This will round to the nearest whole number. eg: 1.2 becomes 1.7 and casting to int makes 1. 3.6 becomes 4.1 and casting makes 4. :)

Comment: Well... no, but that's what you're really doing. A float with no decimal places (no floating point) is an integer. I learnt like this because it helps understand the processes and what's happening. Next time OP wants to make a float from an int they'll know how to go about it. `.2i` won't work!

Answer (score 2):

Why not just cast the `audioPlayer.currentTime` to an integer before you use `stringWithFormat`?

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)(audioPlayer.currentTime)];
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is type-cast the double to an int, like so: `int currentTime_int = (int)audioPlayer.currentTime;`.

You can use this same approach for the other variable.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the shorter answers here will work correctly.  But if you want your code to be really clear and readable, you might want to explicitly specify your desired conversion from float to int, such as using:

```
int tmpInt = floorf(myFloat);  // or roundf(), etc.
```

and then separately specifying how you want the integer formated, e.g.

```
... stringWithFormat:@"%d", tmpInt ...  // or @"%+03d", etc.
```

instead of assuming that an inline cast shows what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use

> double newDvalue =floor(dValue);

it will remove all the decimals point

using %.0f  for string format will be good also