# decimal value rounding off to next higher value in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, currency, rounding

In my app, am accepting amount value(float) and saving it. In the amount field, the user may enter any number of digits after decimal point. But when i read it and save, it should be only two digits after the decimal point. this scenario works properly with my code. but the problem is, if the user enters the value 2.468, it is saved as 2.47. but if the user input is 2.245, in this case i need to be saved as 2.25 but it gets saved as 2.24 only.

and my code is

```
AmountValue = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",[AmountTxt1.text floatValue]];
 float Rate_int = [AmountValue floatValue];

NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:Rate_int]]];

TotalAmtTxt.text = str1;
```

Comment: according to you what will be output of 2.243?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
double Rate_int1 = [input doubleValue];

NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:Rate_int1]];
```

The NSString numberString has the rounded off value..

Answer (score 2):

```
float a=2.245;
float b=ceilf(a*100)/100;
```

or

```
NSNumberFormatter *currencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
    [currencyFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundCeiling];
    [currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
```

Comment: but it is behaving strange.. if i enter 20.245, it gets saved as 20.25. but if i enter 10.245, it gets saved as 10.24 only.. likewise, for some values, it works correctly and for some, it doesn't..

Answer (score 1):

try this Code..

```
 NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
 [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
 [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];
 [formatter setRoundingMode: NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];

 NSString *numberString = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:Rate_int]];

 TotalAmt.txt = numberString;
```

Comment: No.. even after applying the code, 2.245 is getting rounded to 2.24.. i need it to be rounded to 2.25..

Comment: actually according to round function in mathematics,When 3rd digit is 5 and rounding into the 2nd digit, one option is to always round up. The preferred way, however, is to round up if the result(the target digit) would be made even but not if the target digit would be made odd. It cn b shown dat doing it this way introduces less rounding error over a series of calculations.
Example: 2.235 rounded to 2.24 but 2.245 rounded to 2.24 (going up would give 2.25).
Also: 2.755 is rounded to 2.76 but 2.765 is rounded to 2.76
[Check this link..](http://facstaff.unca.edu/tlbrown/RM2/roundingVer2.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

you add this code:

```
[currencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
[currencyFormatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfUp];
[currencyFormatter setMaximumFractionDigits:2];

NSLog(@"%@",[currencyFormatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:2.245]]);
```

Comment: it will print 23.44, but he want it as 23.45

Comment: @Rajneesh071 you enter 2.245 and check question

Comment: @Rajneesh071  Question is :the user input is 2.245, in this case i need to be saved as 2.25

Comment: @Rajneesh071 after dot  third number  is >=5 then is dislplay second number +1 but number  is <=5 second number no increment it mathematically rules......